# How to do a Gradient Layer on the Launch Screen Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to do a gradient Layout in my Launch Screen programmatically. I've used gradient in viewControllers but I don't know how to do this on the launchscreen. Thanks.

Comment: It's the same - you have, by default, in you project `LaunchScreen` storyboard with single view controller, and you are free to customize it as you wish.

Comment: @zgorawski Yes, but the Launchscreen viewController is not linked with a viewController file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way (I know) and is the easiest to get some fancy colors and designs to your LaunchScreen is to import an image and put a `UIImageView` to your LaunchScreen. Voila!

However, if you want to code it, then you can just make a blank LaunchScreen and present a UIViewController that serves as your *second main LaunchScreen* .